# CSS window resizing problems in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Although almost nobody supports IE6 anymore, I've been given the task to design an IE6-compatible webpage.

Here's the code:

```
<body style="background-color: #ccccdd;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server"
        style="margin: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
               background-color: #f1f1f1;">
        <div id="divPage" style="width: 100%">
            <div id="divSelectOption" runat="server">
                <div id="divInstruct" style="float: left;
                    position: relative;
                    display: inline-block;">
                    Select your gender:
                </div>
                <div style="margin-left: 10px;
                    display: inline-block;">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbFemale" runat="server" style="display: block;"
                        Text="Female" GroupName="grpGender" Checked="true" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMale" runat="server" style="display: block;"
                        Text="Male" GroupName="grpGender" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here's the problem:

If an IE6 browser opens the page (whether maximized or restored (meaning when the window only covers part of the screen)), all is displayed normally.

However, if the page is loaded when the browser is maximized, and then the user minimizes it, `divInstruct` gets pushed all the way to the right side of the window.

I apologize in advance if you feel that supporting IE6 is a waste of time, but these are the clients' demands.

I'd appreciate any help.

**UPDATE:** When I remove `width: 100%` from `divPage`'s `style` attribute, the above problem is gone; however, this causes the `margin` attribute of `form1` to stop working. (Only in IE6!)

Comment: this may not be related just to IE6. Can you describe how do you want your UI to be displayed?

Comment: When i tried this in my IE6 browser everything worked fine... didn't get what you meant??

Comment: In other browsers it works fine, so I'm assuming it's an IE6 thing... There might be some other definition somewhere out there that's causing this. There's just so much out there (.css files, master pages etc.) that I don't know where to start looking.
That's why I asked if anyone might know what can cause such a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest checking your external css files carefully, if an invalid selector is passed into IE6, it ignores everything after it.

Also, ensure you're applying a css reset so you're starting from the same css state in each browser.

This doesn't feel like a typical IE6 problem to me. It feels like a coding problem that IE6 isn't able to resolve with the grace of its younger browser cousins.